# c# Regular expression example

Tags: c#, regex

The following are examples of correct input strings:

1,a

2,a,b

3,a,b,c

4,a,b,c,b

and so on...

The first number indicates how many letters follow in the string, and the rest of the letters can be either a,b or c in any order.

Can a regular expression be used to correctly match and capture the first number and each of the letters into groups (and exclude the commas) using Regex.Match?

Comment: Not possible with regular expressions. You have to parse it manually. Which should be even simpler than any regular expression.

Comment: I agree that parsing it manually is very easy, but was trying to do it with a regular expression.  I thought that it might be possible to capture the first digit and then match ,[a-c] the number of times as specified by the first captured digit.

Comment: That could work if you supported only specific set of numbers. Not for generalized count of items.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Regular Expressions to do this, you could just use LINQ.

```
string[] split = string.Split('.');
string number = split.First();
string[] letters = split.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thats not LINQ. Those are just normal string methods.

Comment: I think you'll find the last two lines ARE from LINQ. Only the first isn't.

Comment: `First` and `Skip` are not from `string`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @martin_costello: the first number should match the number of consecutive letters. This is missing in your approach completely.

Comment: The question infers that the number is being given in the input, and does not need to be computed.

Comment: @martin_costello: "match" means that you should return a boolean, some strings are matched, others are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Split` and `LINQ` methods. First you need to validate the input string:

```
var parts = input.Split(',');
bool isMatch = parts.Skip(1)
                    .Count(x => x.Length == 1 &&
                                char.IsDigit(x[0])) == int.Parse(parts[0]);

if(isMatch) 
    var digits = parts.Select(int.Parse);
```

More generally you can write an extension method for that:

```
public static bool IsMatch(this string source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    var parts = source.Split(',');

    if (parts.Any())
    {
        return parts.All(x => x.Length > 0 &&  x.All(char.IsDigit)) && parts.Skip(1).Count() == int.Parse(parts[0]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

This method will match the following strings:

```
1,4
3,456,123,789
5,12,34,11,78,65
```

And won't match the following strings:

```
1,2,3
4,2,1
2,1
1,a
2,1,b
```